# Load D3 Collapsible Tree with data from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, d3.js

Within the app that I am working on, we need to display a collapsible tree graph using D3. The data that will be put into this graph is not stored in a file, but is instead within the database, passed to JavaScript through an Ajax call to a rest service and stored into a var in JSON form.

The Ajax call is returning the correct data, and I am storing it to a var json_data. Here is the Ajax code:

```
var json_data;

jQuery.getJSON("/ux/resources/graph", function(json){
    json_data = json;
    init(); //This calls the entire D3 setup 
});
```

As shown above, I am waiting until after the data is returned to render D3.

Here is my init method.

```
function init(){
    d3.json(json_data, function(error, json) {
        root = json;
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;

        function collapse(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d._children.forEach(collapse);
                d.children = null;
            }
        }

        root.children.forEach(collapse);
        update(root);
    });

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");
};
```

How can I get D3 to recognize the json_data input and create the graph from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d3.json()` does essentially the same thing that `jQuery.getJSON` does: it loads json from a url. So calling `d3.json()` from `init()` is unnecessary if you've already loaded it with jQuery. That aside, the first param to `d3.json()` is supposed to be the URL of the data, not the data itself as you're showing.

Probably the appropriate thing to do is ditch the jQuery `getJSON()` call and just call init right away (and pass the correct the url into `d3.json()`:

```
init();// no $.getJSON() needed

function init(){
  d3.json("/ux/resources/graph", function(error, json) {
    ...
```

If instead you prefer to load the data via jQuery, then just pass the loaded data into the init method and skip the `d3.json()` call:

```
jQuery.getJSON("/ux/resources/graph", function(json){
  init(json); //This calls the entire D3 setup 
});

function init(json) { // json is passed in
  root = json;
  // Notice that here's you're modifying the loaded json.
  // Probably fine, but be aware of it.
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;
  ...
```

Comment: meetamit's suggestion is spot on IMHO. There are a couple of tree diagram examples here ([http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html)) including one with the use of d3.json

Comment: What if I get data from post request ?

Comment: @7H3IN5ID3R sure, why not?

Comment: Just passing the url in Query.getJSON("/ux/resources/graph", function(json){ ?

Comment: @7H3IN5ID3R `jQuery.post("/ux/resources/graph", ...)`. See [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Hey, how come we use the data from variable in drag,pan, collpasible tree d3?

Comment: Hey, why I'm getting red circles here http://animate-visuals-16062016-dot-the-insider.appspot.com/visual where there were no such thing in http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/raw/7880033/ . I just copied the same code.